# Dplyr 1.1.0 update slowing down lag() within case_when()

Tags: r, dplyr

I just updated dplyr to 1.1.0 and have noticed that some of my code is running much slower. I am using a large long dataset from a large cohort study with multiple visits for each individual, so many rows for each id. I am using lag() within case_when() to create a new variable that is 1 or 0 depending on whether that individual had an event at a previous visit within a certain time window. Previously this was running fine and completed within a few seconds on my full dataset, but after the update it now takes 45 minutes to run.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

ids <- rep(c("01A", "02B", "03C"), each = 7)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 21)
events <- sample(c(0, 1), 21, replace = TRUE)

df <- tibble(id = ids, date = dates, event = events)

start_time <- Sys.time()
df2 <- df |>
  arrange(id,date) |> 
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(
    prev_event = case_when(
      event == 1 ~ 0,
      lag(event) == 1 & (date - lag(date) <= 65) & (date - lag(date) >= 15) ~ 1,
      lag(event, n=2) == 1 & (date - lag(date, n=2) <= 65) & (date - lag(date, n=2) >= 15) ~ 1,
      lag(event, n=3) == 1 & (date - lag(date, n=3) <= 65) & (date - lag(date, n=3) >= 15) ~ 1,
      lag(event, n=4) == 1 & (date - lag(date, n=4) <= 65) & (date - lag(date, n=4) >= 15) ~ 1,
      lag(event, n=5) == 1 & (date - lag(date, n=5) <= 65) & (date - lag(date, n=5) >= 15) ~ 1,
      lag(event, n=6) == 1 & (date - lag(date, n=6) <= 65) & (date - lag(date, n=6) >= 15) ~ 1,
      lag(event, n=7) == 1 & (date - lag(date, n=7) <= 65) & (date - lag(date, n=7) >= 15) ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0))
end_time <- Sys.time() 
end_time - start_time
```

Running this code with dplyr 1.0.10 finished in 0.04612994 secs, but after update it takes 1.891139 secs.

My full dataset is 4680 rows with 442 different ids, rather than 21 rows with 3 ids, so this time difference is obviously much more significant with the full data.

I appreciate that this code might not be the most efficient method, but it was working for me and this seems like it could be a bug in the new dplyr update either in the changes to lag() or group_by(). Anyone else had any problems with the update? Or is there a quick fix to this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6674.  No quickfix if you want to continue to use the same approach except to roll back to an earlier version.

Comment: Does using `.by = id` instead of `group_by` change in any way the speed?

Comment: And the question has already been addressed here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75304966/dplyr-v1-1-0-runtime-much-slower-for-case-when-with-grouping-variable

Comment: Quick fix: `cat myscript.R | sed 's/case_when/data.table::fcase/g' | sed 's/~/,/g' > newscript.R`

Comment: Note you could refactor your code to use an overlap join instead of the clunky `case_when()` statement which would also be faster.

Comment: Try replacing `lag` with `flag` from collapse.   In addition, f``lag` is vectorized in `n` so you could calculate all the lags at once.
Also the prior suggestion of using `.by=` seems to help too.

Comment: It has been determined (in dplyr#6674) that the predominant slowdown is in `case_when`. Whether there is some form of change in performance in other dplyr functions is yet to be accepted; I believe there might be a slowdown in [`mutate`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6674#issuecomment-1412191148) itself as well, but that has not been accepted, nor has it be researched as much in depth as `case_when`'s slowdown.